# Remove input date placeholder including slash

Tags: css

I know there is other similar question to this out there. But none of them show how to remove all the placeholder on the input date, only the letters 'dd', 'mm' and 'yyyy'.

I already tried to use this:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:not([aria-valuenow]) {
  color: transparent;
}
```

But like i said, the bars are still there, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egj83yq4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update: This answer no longer works in the latest version of Chrome.

When this answer was originally written, it worked for Chrome v47.

Today, it no longer works in Chrome v60+.

---

#### Original (outdated) answer:

Since the `::-webkit-datetime-edit-text` pseudo element contains the slashes, you can target those elements and set the `color` property to `transparent`.

```css
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: Thank you sr! Everything i found only shows how to hide the letters. Thanks.

Comment: Doesnt work anymore in newer chrome versions (chrome 60.0.3112.113 on win10 pro isnt working)

Comment: @FabianSchöner - Thanks for the heads up. I updated my answer and it works for me now in Chrome v61.0.3163.79 - Ubuntu. Does it work for you now?

Comment: @JoshCrozier well it does "remove" (discolor) the placeholder texts which is exactly whats asked for, but it does hide a valid chosen date-value too.

Comment: Yep, this isn't really that viable if the chosen date is also hidden.